# How to create %tab% in CMD

Tags: tabs, batch-file, cmd

I need reliable way to create %tab% (containing one tab character) for both, Windows and XP.

```
SET TAB=" "
```

Should work for Windows 7 (not tested) but not for Win XP (tested).

This

```
for /F "skip=4 delims=pR tokens=1,2" %%a in ( 'reg query hkcu\environment /v temp' ) do set TAB=%%b
```

works for Win XP only.

Comment: reg query hkcu\environment /v temp gives you the location of the Temp directory. How is this related to what you need to do? What should the `tab` variable contain?

Comment: I need to generate tab character to be used by for loop. THe command created one tab character on Win XP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use an editor which supports TAB characters without changing them to spaces.
And you should reorder the quotes, as with `set TAB=" "` you got a variable with three characters.
TAB contains then also the quotes.

```
set "TAB=   "
```

Currently there seems to be no reliable way to use a program to create a TAB character in all Windows versions on all language platforms.

But you could also use an embedded Jscript snippet.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @goto :Dummy @end/* Batch part

@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"') do set TAB=%%x
echo Tab character is "%tab%"
goto :EOF

***** Now JScript begins *****/
WScript.Echo(String.fromCharCode(9));
```

Answer (score 4):

With robocopy TAB can also be generated.
Robocopy is not available in windows xp by Default.

```
for /f "delims= " %%T in ('robocopy /L . . /njh /njs') do set "TAB=%%T"
```

Answer (score 4):

This method will work universally the same on Win2k, WinXP, Vista, Win7, Win8, Win10

It takes advantage of the fact that the **MZ** header of **PE** executable images that are produced by Microsoft compiler toolset remained the same from nearly 25 years ago in the days of NT3.1 till today in the days of Windows 10.

The byte value at offset 0x46 of the MZ header is 0x09 which is the **TAB** character
So it is sufficient to pick any executable file from windows and grab the TAB from it.

And the most convenient and logical option is to use executable of the Command Processor itself.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

set "TAB="
for /F "delims=" %%Z in (
    '^(type "%COMSPEC%"^|^(^(for /L %%P in ^(1^,1^,70^) do @pause^>nul^)^&set /p "TAB="^&call echo^,%%TAB%%^)^)2^>nul'
) do set "TAB=%%Z"
set "TAB=%TAB:~0,1%"

echo,
echo TAB---^>[%TAB%]^<---TAB  SPACE---^>[ ]^<---SPACE  EMPTY---^>[]^<---EMPTY
echo,
pause
```

**UPDATE April,23,2018**

This is an alternate and more understandable syntax which avoid using pipe and is much faster than the above

```
((for /L %%P in (1,1,70) do pause>nul)&set /p "TAB=")<"%COMSPEC%"
set "TAB=%TAB:~0,1%"
```

**/UPDATE**

to echo the TAB use this form:

```
echo,%TAB%
```

To write the TAB character to a file:

```
:: Creates a new file with TAB character
echo,%TAB%>"NewFile.txt"

:: Appends the TAB character to end of the existing file
echo,%TAB%>>"ExistingFile.txt"
```

Note that **echo** will always appends a new line (CRLF) at the end. If you just want the TAB character without new line use the prompt technic, but keep in mind that this method is **extremely slow** compared to echo so **don't use it excessively**

```
setlocal
set "prompt=%TAB%"
"%COMSPEC%" /d /k<nul>"TAB_Without_NewLine.txt"
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

Incorporate the tab character into your batch file. In particular, place it on the first line, in front of `@ECHO OFF`, then read the first line with the `SET /P` command. It'll read the entire line, of course, so one more `SET` command will be needed to cut the tab character from the line. Here's an example:

```
    @ECHO OFF
<%0 SET /p tab=
SET tab=%tab:~0,1%
ECHO Every%tab%word%tab%is%tab%tabulated
```

Note that the spaces preceding `@ECHO OFF` here are supposed to be a single tab character, like I said earlier.

Comment: It is good idea, but simplier should be create new file with one tab inside, and read this file. And thanks.

Comment: @user1141649: I had that in mind too, but you said you wanted to *generate* the tab character, so I thought keeping it in the batch script would be closer to what you wanted. And with an external file, you would have to remember to keep it together with the batch file (I mean, if you needed to deploy the script somewhere). Anyway, you are right, this would work with an external file just as well.

Comment: @user1141649: Oops, one note, though: this will not work if the file contains a *single* tab character on the line. You'd still need to add more characters or the tab character would be truncated.

Answer (score 3):

The obscure `forfiles` command can be used (or abused?) to generate a tab character (or any other character you prefer, apart from NUL), as discussed in this [DosTips topic](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3857).

Here it is in a nutshell:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims= " %%T in ('
    forFiles /p "." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"
') do set "tab=%%T"
echo(words%tab%separated%tab%by%tab%tabs

endLocal & goto :EOF
```

However, `forfiles` is only available on **Windows Vista** and above. But cheer up, my little **XP** bunnies! You can download a fossilised copy of [forfiles.zip](http://web.archive.org/web/20150810144817/http://www.sharedcache.com/cms/download/forfiles.zip) (22.1kb) thanks to the wondrous [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/).

Comment: put "OBSCURE" on that... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `:makeTab` subroutine below creates a tab character and stores it in the name of the variable passed to it. Requires `certutil`, which is not installed on some versions of **Windows XP**.

```
@echo off & setLocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion

call :makeTab tab
echo(words%tab%separated%tab%by%tab%tabs

endLocal & goto :EOF

:makeTab result=
:: returns tab char in var name given as param
:: requires certUtil
setLocal
set "tabFile=%tmp%\tab.tmp"

if not exist "%tabFile%" (
    >"%tabFile%" echo(09
    certUtil -decodeHex -f "%tabFile%" "%tabFile%" >nul
) %= if =%

for /f "useBack delims=" %%T in ("%tabFile%") do (
    endLocal & set "%1=%%T"
) %= for /f =%
exit /b 0 %= makeTab =%
```

PS: Come to think of it, the above subroutine could be easily extended to generate any character you want (apart from NUL). Watch out for code page issues with characters between ASCII 128 and ASCII 255.

Comment: Nice script!
For anyone wanting to know more about which characters can be generated, my tests seem to show that it's pulling from CP437
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set

Comment: certutil can generate any character, including 0x00 (in one line :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to "use an editor which supports TAB characters without changing them to spaces". 
From command line:

*Method 1* - `forfiles`

```
echo la >t
forfiles /m "t" /c "cmd /c set /p=j0x09"<nul> tab
Copy /y tab+Nul t
type t | ((for /l %N in (1 1 3) do pause)>nul&findstr "^") > t
copy /y t /A tab /B
```

*Method 2*

If you prefer `certutil`:

```
set /p=09<nul> t
certutil -decodehex t tab
```

*Method 3*: - `fsutil`

```
echo la >t
forfiles /m "t" /c "cmd /c set /p=j0x09"<nul> tab
((for /l %N in (1 1 3) do pause)>nul&findstr "^") <tab> t
fsutil file seteof t 1 >nul
```

Tested on Win 10 cmd

Answer (score 1):

[DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/) user aGerman first [reported the presence of a tab character](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=6853#p6853) in the output from `shutdown /?` in 2011, and [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) refined [the technique for extracting it](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=52509#p52509) last May like so:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 " %%T in ('
    shutDown /?
') do set "tab=%%T"
set "tab=%tab:~0,1%"
echo(words%tab%separated%tab%by%tab%tabs

endLocal & goto :EOF
```

**WARNING:** Not guaranteed to work across all versions of **Windows** or all locales. I successfully tested the above on my English language version of **Windows 7 HP** 32-bit, but ymmv.

Answer (score 1):

I've saved the best for last! ;)

Reluctant as I am to contradict an authority such as [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb), his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879650) is over 5 years old, and a technique has since been developed to create a tab character using only native [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) commands, which works on all versions of **Windows** from **XP** onwards.

The `:makeTab` subroutine below is based on code developed in the marathon [Create All ASCII Characters](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5326) topic on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/). It uses `makecab` to create a tab character (ASCII 9) and stores it as a variable with the name passed to it as a parameter:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion

call :makeTab tab
echo(words%tab%separated%tab%by%tab%tabs

endLocal & goto :EOF

:makeTab result=
:: returns tab char in var name given as param
:: based on http://consolesoft.com/batch/binary/genchr.cmd
setLocal
set "tabFile=%tmp%\tab.tmp"

if not exist "%tabFile%" (goto makeTabFile) else goto readTabFile

:makeTabFile
type nul >"%tabFile%"
makeCab /d compress=off /d reservePerDataBlockSize=0 ^
/d reservePerFolderSize=9 "%tabFile%" "%tabFile%" >nul
for /f "skip=28 delims=" %%F in ('find /v "" "%tabFile%"') do (
    >"%tabFile%" echo(%%F
    goto readTabFile
) %= for /f =%

:readTabFile
for /f "useBack delims= " %%T in ("%tabFile%") do (
    endLocal & set "%1=%%T"
) %= for /f =%
exit /b 0 %= makeTab =%
```

The subroutine could be easily modified to create any character you prefer (apart from NUL), so long as you know the ASCII code for the character you want. Beware of code page issues between ASCII 128 and 255.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very simple:

```
set TAB=    "
set "TAB=%TAB:"=%

echo one!TAB!two!TAB!three
```

> one      two      three

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for answers.

Finally I used this simple method:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (delimiter.ini) DO set TAB=%%x
```